# MFC Button Click is Responding to Escape Key

Tags: c++, mfc

When the dialog is opened and the escape key is pressed, a button click event is firing, the dialog should dismiss not run the event.

I have inspected the Resources file in notepad to see what is happening, I have commented out the button in the message map, the issue goes away.  I have no idea why this happening and I cannot find any presets in my code that would cause this to happen

Here is the Dialog in the Resources file

`IDD_SVGDLG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 675, 462
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Export to File",IDC_SVYDLG_EXPORT,173,431,62,24
END`

Here is the message map...

`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSurveyDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_SVYDLG_EXPORT, &CSurveyDlg::OnBnClickedExport)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()`

I expect the dialog to dismiss, export should only run when the button is clicked

Comment: Make a search for all the `OnBnClickedExport` calls in project. Or even for all the `IDC_SVYDLG_EXPORT` entries.

Comment: @Jovibor already tried that, there are no other references to that IDC or event

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `OnBnClickedExport` and look at the call stack when it's hit.

Comment: Maybe IDC_SVYDLG_EXPORT is defined as 2 (IDCANCEL)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That was it!!!!  Thank you so much!  If you move your comment to an answer I'll mark it as correct.  I'll be more careful in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IDC_SVYDLG_EXPORT` is defined as 2, it will be the same value as `IDCANCEL`, and the button will respond to Escape key to cancel the dialog.

ID numbers from 1 to 7 are reserved for standard buttons, `IDOK, IDCANCEL, ...`

It's recommended to use numbers in the range `100` up to `0x7000` for controls. MFC dialog editor may generate its own numbers in this range.

See also [ID Naming and Numbering Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn020-id-naming-and-numbering-conventions?view=vs-2019)